# Sensitive information in plist

Tags: ios, swift, plist, info.plist

I wanna know if it's possible to add sensitive information in info.plist (or another plist).
Now I'm developing a framework, and I need some information, like "app secret" from the app. Is it okay to put this information in plist?

Comment: The short answer is, "it depends". Is your "app secret" just an identifier for the app? Or is it an encrypted key core to your SDKs offering. Or something between. Info.plist can be extracted from the app bundle by anybody and it is not encrypted. So anything in there is assumed public. A semi technical person can easily access the info.plist. A reasonably technical person can access or decompile any binary/package so any secret shipped in any form is likely unsafe. So it all depends on the use case.

Comment: Requiring the value to be in the plist also limits the choices for the framework user. If your framework just exposes a function that they have to call and provide the value then it is their choice how they obtain the value.

Answer (score 0):

Several frameworks that I've used do this.

Probably this is what you are looking for [Access plist from framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72358284/can-we-access-the-plist-inside-a-framework-target-from-the-application)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).